# How to split string in XML

Tags: xml, string, xslt, split

I have this kind of  XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="dataroot">
        <xml><xsl:apply-templates/></xml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="M_17">
        <package id="{package_id}" cat="{cat}">
            <nazwa><xsl:value-of select="nazwa"/></nazwa>
            <xsl:if test="author"><author><xsl:value-of select="author"/></author></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="www"><www><xsl:value-of select="translate(www,'#','')"/></www></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="opis"><opis><xsl:value-of select="opis"/></opis></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="img"><img><xsl:value-of select="translate(img,'#','')"/></img></xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="depends"><depends><xsl:value-of select="depends"/></depends></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="conflicts"><conflicts><xsl:value-of select="conflicts"/></conflicts></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="after"><after><xsl:value-of select="after"/></after></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="replaces"><replaces><xsl:value-of select="replaces"/></replaces></xsl:if>
        </package>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but when there is in eg. depends 2 values which in this code will show

```
<depends>modload com1node</depends>
```

but I want to convert it by followed XSL to:

```
<depends>modloader</depends>
<depends>com1node</depends>
```

This should happened for: depends, conflicts, after and replaces

How to split this strings (if they occur in source XML) into simple ones (one in each line as I show in example)?

Part of Core XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-05-11T15:51:32">
    <Mnc_172>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <package_id>minecraft</package_id>
        <cat>lib</cat>
        <www>#http://minecraft.net/#</www>
        <nazwa>Minecraft</nazwa>
        <author>Mojang</author>
        <opis>Game - build your own world!</opis>
        <img>#/mc.png#</img>
    </Mnc_172>
    <Mnc_172>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <package_id>modloader</package_id>
        <cat>lib</cat>
        <www>#http://minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-x/#</www>
        <nazwa>ModLoader</nazwa>
        <author>Risugami</author>
        <opis>ModLoader - library to load mods</opis>
        <img>#/gen.png#</img>
        <replaces>modL forging</replaces>
    </Mnc_172>
    ...
</dataroot>
```

Comment: See `fn:tokenize` in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/

Comment: I am blank in this kind of stuff. This code is not mine. I have met XSL 5h ago so could you show me how to insert it in this code when there is combinations of codes that I don't fully understand yet.

Comment: Could you post an example of your XML source, please?

Comment: @Admaster, sorry -- I use XQuery and XPath all the time, and they use the same functions so I can point you at the right one, but I don't know/do XSLT.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your suggestion requires XSLT 2.0; OP's stylesheet shows XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Hmm. Might be worth looking into whether the engine being used for execution supports 2.0 -- if 1.0 is being used out of convenience rather than on account of need...

Comment: Added part of source XML, but there is instead of depends replaces, but it has to be for all last 4 fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML does not match your XSLT: `M_17` vs. `Mnc_172`. Anyway, in XSLT 1.0 you need to use a recursive template to tokenize the contents. So try changing:

```
<depends><xsl:value-of select="depends"/></depends>
```

to:

```
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="depends"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="'depends'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and add the following template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="elemName"/>
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $sep)">
            <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $sep)"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $sep)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="$elemName" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I know bout this "mistaces". I have 4 pretty same tables in database.
Code works fine, but don't understand why there is $elemName with and without {}

Comment: @Admaster Do a search for *Attribute Value Template*.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 2.0 has an easy function to tokenize strings, but in XSLT 1.0 you have to be more creative.  The way I would usually attack something like this is with a recursive template which does something with the text before the first space and then calls itself recursively with the remaining text, stopping when it runs out.

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="dataroot">
        <xml><xsl:apply-templates/></xml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="M_17">
        <package id="{package_id}" cat="{cat}">
            <nazwa><xsl:value-of select="nazwa"/></nazwa>
            <xsl:if test="author"><author><xsl:value-of select="author"/></author></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="www"><www><xsl:value-of select="translate(www,'#','')"/></www></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="opis"><opis><xsl:value-of select="opis"/></opis></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="img"><img><xsl:value-of select="translate(img,'#','')"/></img></xsl:if>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="depends | conflicts | after | replaces" />
        </package>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="depends | conflicts | after | replaces">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="concat(normalize-space(), ' ')" />
        <xsl:if test="$text">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ' ')" />
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The trick here is what we do with the `text` parameter.  Initially I'm setting it to `concat(normalize-space(), ' ')`, which means the whole text of the target element with

- leading and trailing whitespace removed
- internal whitespace normalized to a single space character and
- one trailing space added

So `$text` is initially `word1-space-word2-space-...-wordN-space`

Now at each step we create a new element with the same name as the original one and with the first word of `$text` as its content.  We then recurse, passing everything *after* the first space to the next step (i.e. `word2-space-...-wordN-space`).  Eventually we reach the point where `$text` is just `wordN-space`, at which point we produce an element for `wordN` and then finish because `substring-after($text, ' ')` is empty.

Note that

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ' ')" />
</xsl:copy>
```

will copy the namespace declarations that are in scope on the input element.  This is harmless but you may consider it looks a bit messy.  To avoid this you could use

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ' ')" />
</xsl:element>
```

instead.

Comment: There is an error in before track cause this code add smth like that <replaces xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">modL</replaces>

Comment: @Admaster it's not an _error_ as such, simply the way that `<xsl:copy>` copies in-scope namespaces from the source element.  Since these namespaces aren't used within the output element they don't make any difference to the semantics, but if you want to get rid of them for cosmetic reasons then just use `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">...</xsl:element>` instead of `<xsl:copy>...</xsl:copy>`.