# xsl and tokenize with a word

Tags: xslt, delimiter, tokenize, cpu-word

I would like to tokenize string with a word.
I am using str:tokenize() but it seems that delimiter might be only single char, even the delimiter consist of more characters, the tokenize() does search for listed characters in the delimiter.

E.g.

```
InputString : "first|second|third|@@|First|Second|Third  
Delimiter : |@@|  
str:tokenize(&InputString, '|@@|')
```

but this returns 6 rows instead of 2

I need to have it in for-each due to next operations with tokenized "sentences"

What am I doing wrong with str:tokenize() ?

Comment: Are you restricted to an XSLT 1 processor and EXSLT extensions? XSLT 2 or 3 relying on XPath 2 or 3 have the `tokenize` function you could use, although given that its second argument is a regular expression pattern where characters like `|` are meta characters you would need to make sure you run your delimiter through an escape mechanism e.g. `tokenize('"first|second|third|@@|First|Second|Third', '\|@@\|')` finds two tokens: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2e. http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html is a function to escape any characters that need it.

Comment: Xalan , XSLT 1
"\" doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is conforming to the specification for the [`str:tokenize`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) function:

> The second argument is a string consisting of a number of characters.
>   Each character in this string is taken as a delimiting character. The
>   string given by the first argument is split at any occurrence of any
>   of these characters.

---

What you want to do is split the given string at any occurrence of a given **pattern** instead. For this, you need to use the [`str:split`](http://exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html) function - if your processor supports it.

Answer (score 0):

thx for advise.

I am attaching example code which match my needs- may be it would help someone to save his/her time.
It takes element and parse it according to two delimiters, plus it draws all cells (including empty one - even last one is empty). If the second cell/column is empty it will skip whole row.

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>firs t|sec ond|third|@@|First|Second|Third</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>1||3|@@|4|5|6|@@|7|8|</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cdd>
        <title>1|2|@@|3|4|@@||</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cdd>
</catalog>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="str exsl">
    <!-- Edit these parameters if necessary. -->
    <xsl:param name="rowDelimiter" select="'|@@|'"/>
    <xsl:param name="columnDelimiter" select="'|'"/>
    <!-- Edit these parameters if necessary. -->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h2>My test</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <xsl:variable name="ercm_rows">
                            <xsl:call-template name="splitStringToRows">
                                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="title" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$rowDelimiter"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>


                        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($ercm_rows)/ercm_row">
                                  <xsl:if test="./ercm_column[position()=2 != ''] and ./ercm_column[position()=2]/text()"> 
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./ercm_column">
                                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </tr>
                            </xsl:if> 
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>


            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

   <!--  ROWS SPLIT --> 
    <xsl:template name="splitStringToRows">
        <xsl:param name="list" />
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" />


        <xsl:variable name="newlist">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$list" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($list, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newlist, $delimiter)" />
        <ercm_row>
            <xsl:call-template name="splitStringToColumns">
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$first" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$columnDelimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </ercm_row>


        <xsl:if test="$remaining">
            <xsl:call-template name="splitStringToRows">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$rowDelimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  COLUMNS SPLIT -->
    <xsl:template name="splitStringToColumns">
        <xsl:param name="list" />
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" />

        <xsl:variable name="newlist">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$list" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($list, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newlist, $delimiter)" />
        <ercm_column>
              <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
        </ercm_column>

        <!--    <xsl:if test="$remaining" > -->
        <xsl:if test="contains($list, $delimiter)" >
            <xsl:call-template name="splitStringToColumns">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[screenshot of Output vs XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQX9C.gif)

Comment: So which XSLT processor do you use that supports `str:tokenize` but not  `str:split`?

Comment: tokenize is not good for me. it checks char by char and only not delimiter return. In case that first column is empty string it will completely shift all columns . E.g. it will start with the second column as the first one.

Comment: I find this very confusing. Your question is about one thing, your answer seems to be about something else altogether. I am not sure how this is supposed to help anyone.

Comment: it is simple : you said to use str:split instead of tokenize - good advise. I've separated rows to two instead of 6 rows. 

Then the code is extended about to split each row to columns with different delimiter. I looked for similar code but no success - this might be useful if only string in an XML element is available and we need to get it as node type to work with. I am not sure if there is simpler solution for XSLT1 but this one works for me well and may be can help next.

Comment: Splitting the row to columns can be accomplished using either `str:tokenize` or `str:split`. If you have issues with some cells being empty, you should have posted this as a separate question (which would have been closed as a duplicate - for example, of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597058/how-to-split-string-in-xml).